# How to invoke @ControllerAdvice from another project

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

Actually I wrote a global ExceptionHandling using *@ControllerAdvice* for my Sprint boot project in a separate project, *now I want to call it from another project* but seems it doesn't work, since it doesn't override the default exceptions.

I'm developing in Java.

Now I want to know *how to configure both projects* to be able to invoke this global ExceptionHandling class for me from another project. My intention is to use this into several projects.

Thanks inadvance for the help.

Comment: provide it as a library?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by exposing the controller advised class as a @Bean in the config class (class annotated with @SpringBootApplication or @Configuration).

Of course, you need to add the library's pom dependency where your controller advice is.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue & was able to solve.
You're missing @ComponentScan annotation in your Controller Advice class.
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.yourpackage")